# Customizing the Install procedure in InstallShield for DPI

Tags: installshield, software-distribution

I want to turn on the DPI resizing of from the Install Shield such that the font size will be independent to the resolution of the screen. I don't want to ask each customer to change their setting as that would not be practical as well as a bad customer service. So I would like to set up the installer such that when installing I wont have to worry about the setting and set the setting as default when the software is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use feature "DPI-Awareness in the Wizard Interface".

Reference document: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/SteUIDPI.htm

Some configuration related to DPI:

- Check DPI on client machine: DLG_INFO_CHECKSELECTION: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/LangRef/LangrefDLGINFOCHECKSELECTION.htm?Highlight=dpi
- Background About the Default Images on Dialogs in InstallScript and InstallScript MSI Projects: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/ISDefaultDialogImg.htm?Highlight=dpi
- Default Visual Asset Settings: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/DefaultVisualAssetSettings.htm?Highlight=dpi
- `SdOptionsButtons`: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/LangRef/LangrefSdOptionsButtons.htm?Highlight=dpi

and other: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/Search.htm?q=dpi

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll mark this as correct if it helps my problem.